# how to remove a key/value pair from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have a large JSON file that I need to remove every instance of a key/value pair that is

example:

```
"LastModifiedDate" : "2015-05-20T23:41:46.000+0000"
```

from several objects at different levels. The key is always the same but the date-time value is different for each one.

Is there a way to remove all of these using Sublimetext and global replace or a macro? Or possibly some utility like jq?

The issue is I'm trying to serialize this and this key doesn't exist so it fails. I'd like to remove it up front before serialization. If that's not possible I may be able to implement a javascript solution before its serialized.

Answer (score 3):

Try the sublime text search and replace with a regex:

```
"LastModifiedDate".*$
```

and replace with nothing

Answer (score 1):

It's a terse solution because you haven't given much details about the JSON file. This solution should work assuming you have a JSON Array and all of the objects contain this key-value pair. In javascript:

```
for(var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
    delete jsonArray[i]['LastModifiedDate'];
}
```

Sample JSON input data that I assumed is as follows:

```
jsonArray = [{
    "LastModifiedDate": "2015-05-20T23:41:46.000+0000",
    "BookID": "1",
    "Author": "Mr.X"
},
{
    "LastModifiedDate": "2015-05-21T23:41:46.000+0000",
    "BookID": "2",
    "Author": "Mr.Y"
},
{
    "LastModifiedDate": "2015-05-22T23:41:46.000+0000",
    "BookID": "3",
    "Author": "Mr.Z"
}]
```

Upon executing the above javascript code on this data, the value of jsonArray would change to this:

```
[{
    "BookID": "1",
    "Author": "Mr.X"
},
{
    "BookID": "2",
    "Author": "Mr.Y"
},
{
    "BookID": "3",
    "Author": "Mr.Z"
}]
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bv77kyr3/1/):

Answer (score 0):

var s =JSON.stringify(jsonArray);
var p = s.replace(/"LastModifiedDate[^,}]+,/g,'');

NewjsonArray = JSON.parse(p);

Now you have json with out the "LastModifiedDate" key,valu pair.